# Proving an absolute inequality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

No answers please, just hints!

I'm asked to prove that, on $ 0\leq x < \pi$, where $n\in\mathbb N$ and $|\sin(nx)|\leq n\sin x$, that $|\sin((n+1)x)|\leq(n+1)\sin x$ suing the fact that $\sin(x+y)=\sin x \cos y+\cos x \sin y$.

What I've done so far is $\begin{align*} |\sin(nx+x)|&=|\sin(nx)\cos x + \cos(nx)\sin x| \\ &\leq |\sin(nx)\cos x|+|\cos(nx)\sin x| \\ &\leq |\sin(nx)*1|+|\cos(nx)*1| \\ &\leq n\sin x+|\cos(nx)|\end{align*}$

and here I'm stuck

Comment: HINT: Instead of substituting $\sin x$, substitute $\cos(nx)$ in line 2 of your inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Use induction. Use your first step to get $|\sin ((n+1)x)| \leq |\sin (nx)|+|\sin x|$ and the apply induction hypothesis for the first term. You can start the induction argument with the case $n=0$.